# How could I DRY the common methods in different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote setter and getter for the virtual attribute `stock`

For the getter it will aggregate the HAM_MANY relation records.
For the setter, it will create a new record and save the record to the right child table.

How could I DRY the two methods in the two models?

How could I avoid have two identical code in different model files? Thanks

## Model Flight

```
  has_many :stocks, foreign_key: "flight_sku_fare_id", class_name: "FlightSkuFareStock", dependent: :destroy

  def stock
      stocks.sum(:amount)
  end

  def stock=(stock_value)
      self.save
      stock_delta = stock_value - self.stock
      if stock_value >=0 and (stock_delta!=0)
          self.stocks.create(amount: stock_delta)
      end
  end
```

## Model Room

```
  has_many :stocks, foreign_key: "room_sku_id", class_name: "RoomSkuStock", dependent: :destroy


  def stock
    stocks.sum(:amount)
  end

  def stock=(stock_value)
      self.save
      stock_delta = stock_value - self.stock
      if stock_value >=0 and (stock_delta!=0)
          self.stocks.create(amount: stock_delta)
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [active_support/concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

**app/models/concerns/stock_concern.rb**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module StockConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def stock
    stocks.sum(:amount)
  end

  def stock=(stock_value)
    self.save
    stock_delta = stock_value - self.stock
    if stock_value >=0 and (stock_delta!=0)
        self.stocks.create(amount: stock_delta)
    end
  end
end
```

And in your models,

**app/models/flights.rb**

```
class Flight < ActiveRecord::Base
  include StockConcern

  ## other methods
end
```

**app/models/rooms.rb**

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  include StockConcern

  ## other methods
end
```

You might have to tweak it a little bit to make it work perfectly.